# WordPress Woocommerce post id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce, on `view-order` page is there a way to get post id of product (or an other column) ?

I tried to display data of `$_product` and `$item_meta` but it's displaying the id of the product created in the admin of WordPress, not the id of the current product in the order.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get you all the details of the order:

```
  <?php 
      global $woocommerce;
      $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
      $order->get_items();
   ?>
```

Comment: Its doesn't run. Your code displays the id of the product with post_type = "product". But I need the id of the post_type = "tribe_wooticket" which is linked to post_type = "shop_order" that represent my order.

Answer (score 0):

After testing all methods of woocommerce, the only way to do that is to create a custom function that takes in the database the post_title (in wp_posts) that starts with the order id.